# How can I use Fingerprint in Zebble?

Tags: c#, xamarin, zebble, xamarin-zebble

I am working on project that need to authentication base on Touch ID.
I searched on Zebble document and google but I couldn't find the way of working 
with finger-print on Zebble, also I checked Device in Zebble and there wasn't anything

How can I access to the fingerprint Api in Zebble?